# Separar uma coluna em duas no R studio

Tags: r

Tenho um Data Frame no R que em um dos campos a coluna município trás a seguinte configuração:
nome do município junto com a sigla do estado, mas quero separar o município do estado e criar uma nova coluna

Como está:

```
$ municipio: chr "Abadia de Goiás (GO)", "Abadia dos Dourados (MG)", "Abadi…
```

como eu quero que fique :

```
$ municipio: chr "Abadia de Goiás", "Abadia dos Dourados"

$ uf: char "GO", "MG"
```

Usei:

```
    mlt_2 <- mlt %>% separate(municipio, into = c("municipio", "UF"), sep = "()")
```

No entanto ele retorna as colunas separadas com municipio em branco e a uf com as primeira letras dos nomes dos municípios

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

O que acontece é que o argumento do separador (`sep =`) precisa ser pensado como um caractere que vai "cortar" a string para fazer a separação.

Neste sentido, o separador em questão seria um "espaço em branco seguido de um abre parênteses".

Primeiro, vou reproduzir seu dataset:

```
df <- 
  tibble(municipio = c("Abadia de Goiás (GO)", "Abadia dos Dourados (MG)"))
```

Agora, vou fazer a separação usando um espaço em branco (`\\s`) seguido de um abre parênteses (`\\(`), ou seja `\\s\\(`:

```
df %>% 
  separate(municipio, 
           into = c("MUNICIPIO","UF"),
           sep = "\\s\\(")
```

Observe que a função fez o corte justamente nesse ponto

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  MUNICIPIO           UF   
  <chr>               <chr>
1 Abadia de Goiás     GO)  
2 Abadia dos Dourados MG)
```

Aí sobrou um fecha parênteses na coluna de UF para ser retirado. Você pode retirá-lo com a função `stringr::str_remove()`. Ficaria assim:

```
df %>% 
  separate(municipio, 
           into = c("MUNICIPIO","UF"),
           sep = "\\s\\(") %>% 
  mutate(UF = str_remove(UF, pattern = "\\)"))
```

Resultado:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  MUNICIPIO           UF   
  <chr>               <chr>
1 Abadia de Goiás     GO   
2 Abadia dos Dourados MG
```

Outra possibilidade é usando as funções `stringr::str_remove()` e `stringr::str_extract()` dentro de uma função `mutate()`:

Com `str_remove()` você remove o padrão `\\s\\([A-Z]{2}\\)`, ou seja:

- um espaço em branco (`\\s`),
- seguido de um abre parênteses (`\\(`);
- seguido de duas letras maiúsculas (`[A-Z]{2}`);
- seguido de um fecha parênteses (`\\)`)

e com `str_extract()` você extrai o padrão:

- duas letras maiúsculas (`[A-Z]{2}`).

Fica assim:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(MUNICIPIO = str_remove(municipio, pattern = "\\s\\([A-Z]{2}\\)"),
         UF = str_extract(municipio, pattern = "[A-Z]{2}"))
```

Resultado:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  municipio                MUNICIPIO           UF   
  <chr>                    <chr>               <chr>
1 Abadia de Goiás (GO)     Abadia de Goiás     GO   
2 Abadia dos Dourados (MG) Abadia dos Dourados MG
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! vou tentar aqui

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar `*sub` para extrair as informações usando expressões regulares:

```
df <- data.frame(municipio = c("Abadia de Goiás (GO)", "Abadia dos Dourados (MG)", "Abadiânia (GO)"))

df$UF <- gsub("\\((..)\\)|.", "\\1",  df$municipio)
df$municipio <- sub("\\s\\(.*", "", df$municipio)

df
#>             municipio UF
#> 1     Abadia de Goiás GO
#> 2 Abadia dos Dourados MG
#> 3           Abadiânia GO
```

Ou, usando sintaxe do dplyr:

```
df %>% mutate(UF = gsub("\\((..)\\)|.", "\\1",  municipio),
              municipio = sub("\\s\\(.*", "", municipio))
```

### Explicação das expressões

`"\\((..)\\)|.", "\\1"`: remover tudo exceto os dois caracteres entre parenteses:

- `(..)` define um grupo formato por dois caracteres; o `\\1` no *replacement* indica para manter esse grupo
- `\\(` e `\\)` indicam que o grupo se encontra entre parênteses
- `|.` indica todos os caracteres restantes

`"\\s\\(.*", ""`: substituir espaço seguido de parenteses e tudo mais depois por nada (`""`)

- `\\s\\(` indica um espaço seguido de parenteses
- `.*` indica qualquer caractere qualquer número de vezes